# C++ better way to parse values into a vector

Tags: c++, parsing, stl, stream

I am parsing an array of text that come from "C-only" interface and where each string may have an arbitrary amount of values that may, isolatedly, be parsed by a "`istream::operator >>()`".

For example, one of the parsers is for a custom IPv4 class:

```
std::istream &  operator >>( std::istream& stream, IPv4 &var )
```

The implementation is quite obvious.

Now suppose an input like:

```
const char *string_array[] =
{
    "192.168.0.1, 192.168.0.32,    192.168.0.40",
    "169.254.3.18, 169.254.3.19, 169.254.3.20, 169.254.3.21",
    "10.0.92.100",
    "10.0.0.101,    10.0.0.102,    10.0.0.103   ,  10.0.0.104 , 10.0.0.110  ",
};
```

I'd like to find an elegant way to put all of the parsed values in an array so that I can send it to "C-only" functions.

The naive way would be first contatening all of the strings (`const char *`) with a `stringstream` and then loop over this stream with my `operator >>`.

```
        std::stringstream   ss;
        IPv4 ip;
        std::vector< IPv4 > ip_vector;

         for ( int c = 0; c < count; ++c )
                        ss << string_array[ c ] << ", ";

         while ( ss.good( ) )
         {
                        ss >> ip;
                    ip_vector.push_back( ip );
         }
```

It seems not that wise to me, but I can't figure out how to make this smarter.

Note also: Boost is not an option for this solution.

Comment: Are you sure the method that you describe is going to work? You are writing all strings into a stream without separators, so you may end up with fragments like this: `192.168.0.40169.254.3.18`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'll fix my example, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::copy()` and `std::back_inserter` is surely the way out.
I'd stick, though with the `for` loop for iterating through the strings instead of concatenating everything in a `stringstream`, as suggested by @ephemient:

```
std::vector< IPv4 > ip_vector;

for ( unsigned c = 0; c < count; ++c )
{
    std::stringstream   ss( string_array[ c ] );

    std::copy( std::istream_iterator< IPv4 >( ss ), std::istream_iterator< IPv4 >( ),
                std::back_inserter( ip_vector ) );
}
```

This way you make clear you are transforming all the strings.
You also have to construct 3 `std::stringstream` objects, but won't have to relocate memory for concatenating strings.

Answer (score 2):

There's built-in STL functionality that you can use instead of writing your own loops.

```
copy(string_array, string_array + count,
     ostream_iterator<const char *>(ss, ", "));
copy(istream_iterator<IPv4>(ss), istream_iterator<IPv4>(),
     back_inserter(ip_vector));
```

Comment: `std::begin(string_array)` and `std::end(string_array)` should also work as iterator limits.

Comment: @rhalbersma: If you have C++11, yes.

Answer (score 1):

I think that concatenating it's useless: simply 'join' the loops, something like:

```
istream &skipblanks(istream &s) {
  char c;
  while ((c = s.peek()) == ' ' || c == ',')
   s.get();
  return s;
}

...
std::vector< IPv4 > ip_vector;
for ( int c = 0; c < count; ++c ) {
    istringstream ss(string_array[ c ]);
    while (ss) {
        IPv4 ip;
        if (skipblanks(ss) >> ip)
            ip_vector.push_back( ip );
    }
}
```